# How to configure debug port for IntelliJ?

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, port, ddms

Where in IntelliJ can you configure the debug port? Because of the following error in its ADB logs tab

```
ddms: Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700).
Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin 
running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in 
the preferences.
```

I have been searching the Preferences and menu items, but no sign of this setting.  I'm using version 13.1.  In the DDMS preferences I've set the port to 8601 so this 8700 value must surely be coming from IntelliJ.  But how to find it?

Below is an image of my Run configurations dialog (for someone who asked about it).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Take a look in *Run configurations* dialog where you have your run app definition. Then find "Remote" section.

Edit Configurations -> Add "Remote"

[image: Edit configurations dialog]

Comment: would you please be specific about how to find this "Debug section"?  What specific clicks (menu items, buttons, etc) should I make to get to the setting?

Comment: Sorry, at first didn't understand it is about android. Did you try Android Studio? This is IDEA just for Android development. Yesterday was release 1.0 version. Check there.

Comment: I've indeed moved to Android Studio, but the question may indeed be useful to those still using IntelliJ.